# The PDF version of my generated Resume/CV has merged words in the text

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Stackoverflow has a feature where it will generate a PDF version of your Stackoverflow resume/CV. I really like the layout and design. The generated PDF can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/apply/preview-pdf. However, when I markup words in the text with stylization, using either markdown or HTML, the marked-up word will sometimes display merged to another word adjacent to it. It seems to only happen when the other word is the word "and".

For example:

```
...experience with **Java** and **Ruby on Rails**
```

Displays as:

...experience with **Java** and**Ruby on Rails**

The same thing happens with HTML

```
...experience with <b>Java</b> and <b>Ruby on Rails</b>
```

Comment: Is this resume printed by your browser's *print to file* or something else?

Comment: @Paulb: This resume PDF file is generated by Stackoverflow. It is not printed or otherwise generated by my system. You can find it at http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/apply/preview-pdf.

Comment: The issue appears to lie within the PDF renderer that we use. Using the `word-spacing` css rule leads to incorrect rendering. We are in touch with their support team.

Comment: Update: They replied with a "will fix in the next major release". Will write an answer soon.

Answer (score 2):

This is now fixed.

The PDF rendering software that we use has a bug with the `word-spacing` css rule, which lead to the reported issue. We stopped using this rule for PDF exports.

Thank you for your report!